# Getting exception while trying to make an image button's transparent area unclickable

Tags: android

Getting exception when I try to make an image button's transparent area unclickable.Run time exceptions are raised when I tried to implement OnTouchListener. Please help me to solve this issue.

```
ImageButton imgView= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
     imgView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
     imgView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){


    //private final OnTouchListener changeColorListener = new OnTouchListener() {      
         @Override     
         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {        
          Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());        
          int color = bmp.getPixel((int) event.getX(),(int) event.getY());         
         if (color == Color.TRANSPARENT)            
          return false;        
          else {             
         //code to execute
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image button is being clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();             
         return true;         
         }     
         }


         });
}
```

}

MainActivity.XML File

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/worldfinal"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="SELECT A DESIRED COUNTRY" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="93dp"
    android:src="@drawable/india1" 
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"  />
```

Log file is

```
    08-06 10:52:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(329): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-06 10:52:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(329): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-06 10:52:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:367)
08-06 10:52:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at com.sunojsworkshop.MainActivity$1.onTouch(MainActivity.java:34)
08-06 10:52:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3881)
08-06 10:52:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
08-06 10:52:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
08-06 10:52:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
08-06 10:52:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
08-06 10:52:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1691)
08-06 10:52:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1125)
08-06 10:52:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2096)
08-06 10:52:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1675)
08-06 10:52:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2194)
08-06 10:52:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1878)
08-06 10:52:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-06 10:52:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-06 10:52:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-06 10:52:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 10:52:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-06 10:52:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-06 10:52:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-06 10:52:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Are you sure that "@drawable/india1" exists in your drawable folder?

Comment: when the exception gets thrown v.getDrawingCache() is null?

Answer (score 0):

One of your resources is missing from the drawable folder may be it is @drawable/india1

Answer (score 0):

If india1 image exists try the following :

```
    public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {
     Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap( v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);                
     Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
     v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height);
     v.draw(c);
     return b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Implement this method:

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {
     Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap( v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);                
     Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
     v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height);
     v.draw(c);
     return b;
}
```

and in you OnTouchListneners OnTouch:

```
@Override     
         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {        
          Bitmap bmp = loadBitmapFromView(v);     
          int color = bmp.getPixel((int) event.getX(),(int) event.getY());         
         if (color == Color.TRANSPARENT)            
          return false;        
          else {             
         //code to execute
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image button is being clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();             
         return true;         
              }     
            }
         });
```